# Does anybody knows a software that tracks multiple projects and resources?

Tags: project-management, resource-management, ppm, multiple-projects

I am looking something that:

- Allows me to create projects (with a duration) and assign needed roles for them (I don't care about tasks or a gantt chart in this tool, just a project view)
- Allows me to create people with one or more roles
- Set desired start range date for each project
- Calculate what people to assign to the project and a concrete start date:

  - this calculation could also indicate that there is not enough people to start the project, showing the next available start date and the missing roles to start in the desired date
  - this calculation could reallocate people to solve the problem.
- When a new project is received could be added to the portfolio and recalculate.

I have googled a lot about this and all I was able to find were papers describing genetic algorithms or heuristics to resolve the problem, but haven't seen a software that actually solves it. (I suppose its a NP-Hard problem)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's always been a pet peeve of mine when people use "resources" to mean "people".  It's a bit dehumanizing and humiliating.

Comment: Edited the question, agree that people is better than resource in this case (english not my first lenguage, sorry!)

Anyway, the problem itself could apply to any resource like hardware, physical space, etc. My specific question is about people.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help, but I have to admit I dont know if it realy fits your needs (its quite complex to me):
[Polarion](http://www.polarion.com/)

Comment: Not really what I am looking. It seems more like a requeriments mangament application.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Our software solution, TrackerSuite.Net, provides tools for [online project management](http://www.trackersuite.net/web_project_management.html) and [resource availability analysis](http://www.trackersuite.net/scrn_resource_availability.html). I think it will provide the features you are looking for, including project portfolio tracking and management, role based assignments, scheduling and workload tracking. It will also facilitate budget creation and tracking for projects. If you would like a hands on evaluation, you can register on the site (http://www.TrackerSuite.Net) for immediate access to a demonstration site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Trello](https://trello.com/)? I use it to manage projects and upload attachments, files, etc.

It sounds like it would fit what you need perfectly.